# Spring retry XML equivalent to @EnableRetry

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry

I have to work with a project where I cannot use Java-Config for Spring, but I have to use XML-Config. Now I am looking for an XML-Config equivalent to @EnableRetry from Java-Config.

I want this line to work.

```
@Retryable(SQLException.class)
public void saveOrUpdate(Entity entity)
```

Comment: The Spring Retry project on Github offers [an example of xml configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry#xml-configuration). You will have to configure your own aop settings for that matter.

Comment: so there is no equivalent to @EnableRetry?

Comment: If you mean a special Spring XML tag for that, as far as I know, there is not such thing.

Comment: okay solved it by adding a empty class with '@Configuration' und '@EnableRetry'. It gets picked up by the xml configuration.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, `@EnableRetry` on an empty `@Configuration` will work (comment by OP).

Just for completeness, here's the [equivalent in XML](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/issues/27#issuecomment-118084671).

```
<context:annotation-config />

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<bean class="org.springframework.retry.annotation.RetryConfiguration" />
```

**EDIT**

Complete example using XML to enable retry:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("context.xml")
public class So31923175Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So31923175Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(Foo app) {
        return args -> {
            try {
                app.retry("foo");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
    }

    @Component
    public static class Foo {

        @Retryable
        public void retry(String param) {
            System.out.println(param);
            throw new RuntimeException("test retry");
        }

    }

}
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <bean class="org.springframework.retry.annotation.RetryConfiguration" />

</beans>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>net.gprussell.filemailer</groupId>
    <artifactId>so31923175</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>so31923175</name>
    <description>Mail non-empty files passed on the command line</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

and

```
foo
foo
foo
java.lang.RuntimeException: test retry
```

Comment: As soon as I include RetryConfiguration in context, the context is not getting loaded successfully.

Comment: Is there a full example of this with adding the context, aop xml namespace.

Comment: I added a complete example to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

My experience after trying out the above seems a little different as I was trting to find a way of using the XML config approach.

1) I had tried using this feature in my Service implementation class by specifying the @Retryable on specific methods, but WITHOUT the @Configuration and @EnableRetry at the class level. The retry feature did not work.

2) I had also tried adding an empty class with @Configuration and @EnableRetry at the class level. Then, configure that class as a spring bean in XML config. The retry feature did not work here, either.

3) The only way it seems to work is when the @Configuration and @EnableRetry annotations are specified on the Service implementation class.

I am not sure if I am missing anything for Point# 1 and 2.

Comment: Any solution for the above issue?